# Losing Nav Active State in Menu

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, navigation

In the following section:

```
http://www.zimmernutrition.com.php53-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/learning-center/
```

In the sidebar, if you click "Health Articles" and click one of the categories, the active "orange" state of "Learning Center" is lost.  Articles are a custom post type (CPT) and the categories are a related custom taxonomy.

Not sure if the menu is coded incorrectly, the CPT, the custom taxonomy, or some combination.

Comment: Your link is returning a 404.  But, chances are you are going to need to add a lot more info to your question.  What have you tried?  Where do you think it is failing?  Any relevant code??